# How can I save my output image arrays into a specific folder on my computer from my python code in JupyterLab workbook?

Tags: python, arrays, directory, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a for loop in python on Jupyter Notebook to turn a .png image into an array and add regions. When I have 5 arrays in the output, I can't figure out how to save them to a specific folder on my computer.

I seriously have no clue what command I need to use to save them there, or where to find such a command. The only answers I can find online are specific to saving outputs to a .txt file, which is not what I need. I need the images in the outputs saved to a folder.

I'm very new to programming, so forgive my lack of information as I don't know what you all need to know to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere I looked had options for "save as text file" or some variation, and finally I found a single, one-line command to save the outputs into a folder that I could specify.

I used the `cv2.imwrite()` command:
`cv2.imwrite(output_dir, final_img.astype(np.uint8))`

where `output_dir` was defined as the folder-path I made for them to be saved to and `final_img` was the name of the variable given to the arrays after I had completed manipulating them. The last part (`astype(np.uint8)`) was to save it as an 8-bit image.

Hope this helps anyone else with this problem.